# R: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: r

I use script for Google Analytics auth from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095321/7078498) with small changes:

```
library(googleAuthR)
library(googleAnalyticsR)

setwd("C:/seo_bi")

file.exists('humbertoharbert.json')

gar_auth_service(
  json_file = 'humbertoharbert.json',
  scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics"
)
```

And get an exeption:

```
> file.exists('humbertoharbert.json')
[1] TRUE
> gar_auth_service(
+   json_file = 'humbertoharbert.json',
+   scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics"
+ )
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

File is in the working directory. The filename is correct. OS is Windows 10.
Cannot find the solution. Please, help.

UPD.
Result for function from exeption:

```
 >normalizePath(path.expand('humbertoharbert.json'))
[1] "C:\\seo_bi\\humbertoharbert.json"
```

Comment: What does `path` return?

Comment: Shouldn't the slash be a backslash, i.e. C:\seo_bi ?

Comment: I updadet the post with function from the exception.

Comment: Source code of gar_auth_service function is here https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR/blob/f77910fa3255f72a2ed20b0a180885cfbbf763d4/R/googleAuthR_auth.R

Comment: There does look to be an issue with capitalisation and normalizePath https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16369

Comment: There was bug with service account file. There was no private_key. I changed json file for correct one and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

There was bug with service account file. There was no private_key in it. I changed json file for correct one and now script works.

Comment: and what is that corrected json?, can you share it if no issues?