# Getting Error in readRDS(cache_path) : error reading from connection

Tags: r, httr

I am trying to solve quiz 2 in Coursera for Getting and Cleaning Data. I get the error :`"Error in readRDS(cache_path) : error reading from connection"` when I execute the following statement:
`ONgithub_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)`

I have searched and see that there are solutions for `readRDS(file)` but not `readRDS(cache_path)`.
I am on Windows10, R version is 3.3.0
Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Try installing the dev version of httr

Comment: s952163, Try reading through the following response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819293/authorization-code-for-github-api-used-in-r